# Variable-length arrays are created on heap, but we cannot free them?

Tags: c, arrays

I've verified that variable-length arrays are created on heap (see code below), but we cannot use a free operation to free them (cause a fault trap 6).

I was taught that the heap is managed by user and thus we have to explicitly free anything on heap if we don't need them. So who will be responsible to free these memories? Is this a defect of C?

---

Code that shows variable-length arrays are created on heap. (Platform: Mac OS X, gcc, 64bits)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int a1[10];
    int a2[n];
    int a3[10];

    printf("address for a1:%p,address for a2:%p, address for a3:%p\n",a1,a2,a3);
    printf("a1-a2: %lx, a1-a3: %lx\n",(a1-a2),(a1-a3));

    //free(t); // will cause fault trap 6

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
$ ./run 10
address for a1:0x7fff5d095aa0,address for a2:0x7fff5d0959e0, address for a3:0x7fff5d095a70
a1-a2: 30, a1-a3: c
```

It's obvious that a1 and a3 is consecutive and thus are on stack, but a2 has a lower address, thus on heap.

Comment: No - the VLA is on the stack in this particular case, but it's placed after the other local variables (for obvious reasons). Wherever it's located though, it would be wrong to try and free it explicitly.

Comment: @PaulR Quick, Batman, to the answer box !

Comment: "variable-length arrays are created on heap" – nope. If you `printf("%p", malloc(1));` it will probably yield an address *far away* from both your statically-sized local variables and your VLA. The extra space before/after the VLA is probably just alignment/padding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of dynarray.

Comment: See [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/alloca.html).

Comment: @Quentin: heh - I'm not sure the question is worth a full answer, as it's based on a false premise (as noted above!) and should probably therefore be closed.

Answer (score 4):

Variable length arrays have automatic storage duration and have either block scope or function prototype scope.

So this array

```
int a2[n];
```

has automatic storage duration and the block scope of the function main. It was not created in the heap. It is the compiler that generates the corresponding code to free the allocated memory for the array when the control will exit the block scope.

According to the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 7 For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its
>   lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of
>   the program leaves the scope of the declaration.35) If the scope is
>   entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each
>   time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate.

You may apply function `free` only to objects that were allocated using one of the memory allocation functions like malloc, calloc or realloc.

Answer (score 2):

How an implementation allocates storage for VLAs is implementation defined. VLAs have automatic storage duration and you should not try to `free()` it.
You should treat it just like any other local variable for all practical purposes.

You only free() whatever the memory you allocated using `malloc()` family functions.

VLAs are not supported by all implementation and it is a conditional feature.

The macro

```
_ _STDC_NO_VLA_ _
```

is used to test if VLAs are supported or not by implementation (if it's 1 then VLAs are not supported).

In my opinion, VLAs should not used mainly because:

- They are optional in C11
- The allocation failure is not portable detectable

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a defect of C?

Absolutely not. You made several wrong assumptions, which lead you to a wrong conclusion.

First, let's get terminology straight: "stack" is called *automatic storage area*; "heap" is called *dynamic storage area*. C standard does not make any claims about any of the things listed below:

- Relative order of addresses in automatic and dynamic areas
- Relative order of addresses of items within the same storage area
- Presence or absence of gaps between allocations within the same area

This makes it impossible to determine if a variable is in an automatic or in a dynamic area simply by looking at numeric addresses, without making a guess. In particular, what appears "obvious" to you has nothing to do with what is actually happening.

> So who will be responsible to free these memories?

You are responsible for calling `free` on everything that you allocated in the dynamic storage area. You do not allocate your variable-length array in the dynamic storage area<sup>*</sup>, hence you are not responsible for calling `free` on it.

<sup>*</sup> If a compiler implementation were to allocate a VLA in the dynamic storage area, the compiler would be responsible for calling `free` on that pointer.